# Check external links for rel attribute and expand it with "noopener"

Tags: jquery, object, properties, attributes

I have the following concern:

I select external links via jQuery and give them an attribute `target="_ blank"`. After doing this, I select all elements with `target="_ blank"`. Then I would like to check all already defined values of `rel` object-oriented for noopener. Only if no `noopener` is set in `rel` the existing values be supplemented with `noopener`.

```
/**
* detect external links and add target=_blank and then add rel="noopener"
*/
$('a:external').attr('target', '_blank');
$('a[target="_blank"]').each(function() {
    object = [];
    var relAttr = $(this).prop('rel');
    object.push(relAttr.split(' '));
});
console.log(object);
```

I have the code so far. Problem is: if static "accidentally" more than just a space is set, it no longer separates correctly. Also, I simply can not find a solution to search the existing object for noopener, and if it does not exist, replace it. I am still a beginner and google unfortunately could not help me.

Thank you! :)